# Disable jQuery effect with jQuery on by removing class on click

Tags: jquery

I'd like to have two states for a tiny search form: hidden and shown.

In hidden, I'd like to create a `:hover` effect but a CSS transition seemed to clash with jQuery functions applied later. So I created it with jQuery instead.

Now, I'd like the `:hover` effect to disappear altogether when a click invokes the alternative state of 'shown'. I tried that by removing the CSS class that identifies the element for the `:hover` effect but this doesn't really work. More precisely: it's a complete tragedy. The `:hover` effect even takes place *during* the flying in of the search box!

I think jQuery somehow doesn't update its representation of the DOM at `.on('click'` so the "mouseenter" event handler is not dissociated with the `form input` when its class is removed. But that's just a wild guess.

Does anybody have a suggestion for how to accomplish the desired effect? It should be reversible too because I'd like to enable the visitor toggling between the hidden and shown states of the search box.

I wrote this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RubenGeert/yLu7B/1/). The basic script is

```
$(function(){

    // CSS TRANSITION EFFECT IN
    $('form.hidden').on('mouseenter',function(){
        $(this).animate(
            {'right':'-8em'},{duration:200,queue:false});
        })

    // CSS TRANSITION EFFECT OUT
    $('form.hidden').on('mouseout',function(){
        $(this).animate(
            {'right':'-9em'},{duration:200,queue:false});
        })

    //FLY IN ON CLICK, REMOVE TRANSITION EFFECT
    $('form.hidden').on('click',function(){
        $(this)
            .removeClass('hidden')
            .animate({'right':'2em'},1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as the target element selector has to be evaluated dynamically

```
$(function () {

    // CSS TRANSITION EFFECT IN
    $(document).on('mouseenter', 'form.hidden', function () {
        $(this).animate({
            'right': '-8em'
        }, {
            duration: 200,
            queue: false
        });
    })

    // CSS TRANSITION EFFECT OUT
    $(document).on('mouseout', 'form.hidden', function () {
        $(this).animate({
            'right': '-9em'
        }, {
            duration: 200,
            queue: false
        });
    })

    //FLY IN ON CLICK, REMOVE TRANSITION EFFECT
    $(document).on('click', 'form.hidden', function () {
        $(this)
            .removeClass('hidden')
            .animate({
            'right': '2em'
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```